# 3d ArrayList vs arrayList of stack

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to recreate a board game. This board game has a 4x4 dimension which can be represented by a 2D arraylist. However, what i'm having difficulty doing is deciding what would be the best method of implementing a 4x4 board game where each row and column can hold 4 items(In the fashion of a stack where the top item is the greatest int). Would a 2D arraylist of stacks be the most efficient in this case, or would a 3D arraylist be the way to go. Similarly, how would I initialize a 3D arraylist of integers? Thanks!

Comment: How often are you going to read or change particular value from a single field on the Board ?

Comment: @EvcanMustafa Well a player is allowed to place a value greater than that in the original spot. For instance, if [0][0] had 2, another person can put a 3 into that spot. The maximum number of slots = 4 and the max int = 4. I would also need to return the top values and values on the board.

Comment: Why does the board needs to be that much efficiënt. If the players play - let's say one move per second - you won't notice a difference between the two implementations. Since the number of items is fixed however, a 3d array should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efficiency is going to be fine either way, do whatever is easiest for the kinds of things you need to do with the squares. Will you be referencing things by their X,Y coordinates? Then you might want to just use a 2-d array of tiles, so you can reference things as

```
tile = board[x][y]
```

This assumes that the origin is at the top-left of the board. It's also very efficient, if that were actually an issue.

Comment: in this implementation, if I were to add an integer at [0][0] such as 3 and then replacing it with a 4, wouldn't I need another arraylist to keep track of the two integers.

Comment: For your own sanity, just make a `Tile` class which can store 4 integers.  If you start going past 2 dimensions on an array, it gets really hard to read quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You asked *"...what would be the best method of implementing a 4x4 board game..."*. But it seems like you should not care about the implementation right now. It sounds like you should care about the *interface*. Define an interface that precisely mirrors what you want to would like to represent:

```
interface Board {
    int getNumRows();
    int getNumCols();
    int getStackHeight(int r, int c);
    int getStackValue(int r, int c, int h);
 }
```

As it was mentioned before, efficiency should hardly be an issue, and IF it becomes an issue, you'll probably be glad when you can change your implementation without affecting anything else in your game.