# How would I make a board using 3d generic array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How would I make a board using the 3d generic array that contains col, row, and the stack (contains 4, 3, 2, 1).

This is what I declared:

```
private int row, col, stack;
int[][][] array3Dboard = new int[row][col][stack];
```

I just having trouble how to make an board using the multidimensional.

```
public void initalized(int arg1){
    this.playerID = arg1;
    this.array3Dboard = new int[4][4][4];

    //create a data structure for the current contents of the board and stacks.

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is it just me or is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/22312133 ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the class with method initialized() has int[][][] array3Dboard declared as an instance variable.

You also need to write:

```
int row = 4;
int col = 4;
int stack = 4;

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < stack; k++) {
            array3Dboard[i][j][k] = 0; //replace 0 with some numerical value
        }
    }
}
```